# How to group data by column and apply a self-defined function to each small group

Tags: r, function, grouping, plyr

I have a medication dataset which has information about each patient and the medication they have:

```
              Record.ID            Label.Name        Generic.Medication.Name Strength Quantity Days.Supplied Date.of.Fill   GCN GC3         NDC category
    4      aaaaa            CRESTOR TAB 20 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 20 MG    20 MG    30000            30   2014-06-18 19154 M4D 00310075290  statins
    5      aaaaa            CRESTOR TAB 20 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 20 MG    20 MG    90000            90   2014-06-25 19154 M4D 00310075290  statins
    6      aaaaa            CRESTOR TAB 20 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 20 MG    20 MG    90000            90   2014-09-30 19154 M4D 00310075290  statins
    7      aaaaa            CRESTOR TAB 20 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 20 MG    20 MG    90000            90   2014-12-18 19154 M4D 00310075290  statins
    8      aaaaa            CRESTOR TAB 10 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 10 MG    10 MG    90000            90   2014-12-18 19153 M4D 00310075190  statins
    60     bbbbb        TELMISARTAN TAB 20 MG          TELMISARTAN TAB 20 MG    20 MG    90000            90   2014-01-24 23833 A4F 00054054218     RASA
    61     bbbbb        TELMISARTAN TAB 20 MG          TELMISARTAN TAB 20 MG    20 MG    90000            90   2014-04-03 23833 A4F 00054054218     RASA
    62     bbbbb        TELMISARTAN TAB 20 MG          TELMISARTAN TAB 20 MG    20 MG    90000            90   2014-07-21 23833 A4F 00054054218     RASA
    63     bbbbb        TELMISARTAN TAB 20 MG          TELMISARTAN TAB 20 MG    20 MG    90000            90   2014-10-22 23833 A4F 00054054218     RASA
    66     ccccc ENALAPRIL MALEATE TAB 2.5 MG   ENALAPRIL MALEATE TAB 2.5 MG   2.5 MG    15000            30   2014-01-06   963 A4D 00378105101     RASA
```

I have a function called calc_adherence <- function(fill, year) which input a dataset and return a line:
for example,

```
    fill <-  
            Record.ID                  Label.Name        Generic.Medication.Name Strength Quantity Days.Supplied Date.of.Fill   GCN GC3         NDC category
        4      aaaaa            CRESTOR TAB 20 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 20 MG    20 MG    30000            30   2014-06-18 19154 M4D 00310075290  statins
        5      aaaaa            CRESTOR TAB 20 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 20 MG    20 MG    90000            90   2014-06-25 19154 M4D 00310075290  statins
        6      aaaaa            CRESTOR TAB 20 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 20 MG    20 MG    90000            90   2014-09-30 19154 M4D 00310075290  statins
        7      aaaaa            CRESTOR TAB 20 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 20 MG    20 MG    90000            90   2014-12-18 19154 M4D 00310075290  statins
        8      aaaaa            CRESTOR TAB 10 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 10 MG    10 MG    90000            90   2014-12-18 19153 M4D 00310075190  statins
```

the function return me

```
 Record.ID            Label.Name        Generic.Medication.Name Strength Category First_fill  Last_fill Duration DaysCovered Year Method Adherence
    aaaaa         CRESTOR TAB 20 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 20 MG    20 MG  statins 2014-06-18 2014-12-18 197 days         197 2014    PDC         1
```

My question is, now I want to first group the medication dataset by Record.ID and category, and then apply the calc_adherence to each small group so I can have the result for each patient and each medication they take..
I try

```
ddply(category.medication, c('Record.ID','category'), summarize, function(x) calc_adherence(x, year)),
```

but this does not working..
The final dataset I would like is

```
 Record.ID               Label.Name        Generic.Medication.Name Strength Category First_fill  Last_fill Duration DaysCovered Year Method Adherence
    aaaaa         CRESTOR TAB 20 MG ROSUVASTATIN CALCIUM TAB 20 MG    20 MG  statins 2014-06-18 2014-12-18 197 days         197 2014    PDC         1
    aaaaa          ...                                                       RASA    ...                                                PDC         0.8                               
    bbbbb          ...                                                       RASA    ...                                                PDC         0.75
```

Comment: sorry to mention, year is '2014'

Comment: so, `list1 <- split(df, df$Record.ID)` and then `rbindlist(lapply(list1, function(x))`?

Comment: Can you also provide the function `calc_adherence <- function(fill, year)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
aggreagate
```

For example, if your data is named "data"

```
 aggregate(data, by = list(data$Record.ID), calc_adherence)
```